# how can i crate a custom shadow on flutter?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to give shadow for edges of image and the shadow  that i gave with boxshadow was square shadow.I dont want this shape. I just want that the shadow take form according to image. How can i do 
here is my code for shadow :

```
 Container (

              decoration:BoxDecoration(

                image: DecorationImage(
                 image: 
                 AssetImage('images/image 2.png'),),
                boxShadow:[

                  BoxShadow(
                 color:Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 
                  offset: Offset(0,4),
                  blurRadius:4,

                   ),
                   ],
              ),

             // child:Image.asset('images/image 2.png'),

             ),
```

and here is my ui : 
[image]

But i dont want like this
how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using it by editing https://pub.dev/packages/shadow.

Maybe edit to add a color filter for copied shadow image